# How can a module get the path of the file that is importing it in python?

Tags: python, os.path

I have the file `app.py` that imports `module.py`. I need to find out the path of `app.py`, ex: `/home/user/app/app.py`, it works fine in the same folder but when I call `app.py` from a different folder, and my current directory is `/home/user` I get my current directory instead of the directory where `app.py` is.

This is the contents of module.py.

`os.getcwd()` <-- this returns my working path

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` <-- this returns the module path

What is the best approach for this? I'm kind of stuck and did not find anything on Google about it.

Comment: Don't you just want: `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)`?

Comment: os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__) <-- this still gives me the module path, i want the path of the file calling the module!

Comment: i forgot to mention  this is inside module.py [ os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__) ]

Comment: if app.py is the script you're calling you may be able to use: `print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])))`

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: this works like a charm tanks alot was trying to get it right since yestarday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following lines of code in the module you are importing:

**Module.py**

```
import inspect

# Return the frame object for the caller's stack frame.
frame = inspect.currentframe()

# Get calling rame from list of all call frames.
calling_frame = inspect.getouterframes(frame)[1][0]

#Prints a traceback tuple.
print inspect.getframeinfo(calling_frame)
```

---

Also, there is one more hack that you can try. I won't suggest it for production code but its just for fun :) :

```
1. Generate the exception in your module.
2. Catch it and find the Traceback.
3. Manipulate the Traceback according to you requirement.
```

Comment: tanks but this done the job for me outputs the correct path --> os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

Comment: This will only work when you want the path of the program you are running.While the solution i gave is kinda generic one. If you find that helpful please mark as answered.

Comment: il only want the path of the program i'm running cant mark as answered unless @c4urself gives me an answer instead of a comment